# generic line syntax parser in python

Tags: python, parsing

THE PROBLEM:
I'm looking for a python library that might already implement a text parser that I have written in another language.

I have lines of text that represent either configuration commands in devices or dynamic output from commands run on devices. For simplicity, let's assume each line is parsed independently. 
The bottom line is that a line contains fixed keywords and values/variables/parameters. Some keywords are optional and some are mandatory and in specific order. The number and type of variables/values associated with / following a given keyword can vary from one keyword to another.

SOLUTION IN OTHER LANGUAGE:
I wrote generic code in c++ that would parse any line and convert the input into structured data. The input to the code is
1. the line to be parsed and 
2. a model/structure that described what keywords to look for, whether they are optional or not, in what order they might appear and what type of values/variables to expect for each (and also how many values/variables). 
In c++ the interface allows the user among other things to supply a set of user-defined callback functions (one for each keyword) to be invoked by the parsing engine to supply the results (the parsed parameters associated with the given keyword). The implementation of the callback is user-defined but the callback signature is pre-defined.

WHAT ABOUT PYTHON?
I'm hoping for a simple library in python (or a completely different direction if this is something done differently/better in python) that provides an interface to specify the grammar/syntax/model of a given line (the details of all keywords, their order, what number and type of parameters each requires) and then does the parsing of input lines based on that syntax.

I'm not sure how much argparse fits what I need but this is not about parsing a command line input thou similar.

AN EXAMPLE:
Here is an example line from the IP networking world but the problem is more generic:
`access-list SOMENAME-IN extended permit tcp host 117.21.212.54 host 174.163.16.23 range 5160 7000`

In the above line, the keywords and their corresponding parameters are:

```
key: extended, no parameters
key: permit, no parameters 
key: tcp, no parameters
key: host, par1: 117.21.212.54
key: host, par1: 174.163.16.23
key: range, par1: 5160, par2: 7000
```

This is a form of firewall access control list ACL. In this case the parser would be used to fill a structure that indicates

```
- the name of the ACL (SOMENAME-IN in the above example)
- the type of ACL (extended in the above example but there are other valid keywords)
- the protocol (tcp in the above example)
- the src host/IP (117.21.212.54 in the example)
- the src port (optional and not present in the above example)
- the dst host/IP (174.163.16.23 in the example)
- the dst port (a range of ports from 5160 to 7000 in the above example)
```

One can rather easily write a dedicated parser that assume the above example specific syntax and checks for it (perhaps this might also be more efficient and more clear since targeted to a specific syntax) but what I want is to be able to write a general parsing code, where all the keywords and the expected syntax is provided as data / model to the parsing engine which uses it to parse the lines and is also capable of pointing out errors in the parsed line.

I'm not obviously looking for a full solution cause that would be a lot but I hope for thoughts specifically in the context of using python and reusing any features or libraries python may have to do such parsing.

Thanks,
Al.

Comment: Are [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) a good solution to your problem? If not, can you edit your question to provide a few sample lines of input and the expected output for those, so we can try to work something up?

Comment: Can you post a few examples of lines to be parsed?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I added an example and apologize the description is now long (too long)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly (and it is possible that I don't, because it is hard to know what limits you place on the possible grammars), then you should be able to solve this problem fairly simply with a tokeniser and a map of keyword parsers for each command.

If your needs are very simple, you might be able to tokenise using the `split` string method, but it is possible that you would prefer a tokeniser which at least handles quoted strings and maybe some operator symbols. The standard Python library provides the `shlex` module for this purpose.

There is no standard library module which does the parsing. There are a large variety of third-party parsing frameworks, but I think that they are likely to be overkill for your needs (although I might be wrong, and you might want to check them out even if you don't need anything that sophisticated). While I don't usually advocate hand-rolling a parser, this particular application is both simple enough to make that possible and sufficiently different from the possibilities of a context-free grammar to make direct coding useful.

(What makes a context-free grammar impractical is the desire to allow different command options to be provided in arbitrary order without allowing repetition of non-repeatable options. But rereading this answer, I realize that it is just an assumption on my part that you need that feature.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I reached similar conclusions for c++ which is why I wrote my own implementation (aside from the fun of doing so). I was not sure whether for python the same conclusions would be true but now I know they rather are thanks to your answer. I had doubts just because python is used widely for processing text so there was a chance a simple parser might be out there (I didn't want a complicated parser that would taken me longer, than writing my own simpler logic, to understand and use).